# Adding further filters to a query

Tags: sql

I've got the following query which works, but now I'm stuck. I would like to add a further two filters and I am not quite sure how to do this,. In the table relation I have a field called relationship. I need to make sure that the father data returned either has father or stepfather in that field. Similarly I need the mother data to be filtered by Stepmother, mother. Of course a pupil may not have a father or a mother but I still want the data to be returned if they have one parent.

```
WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') AND rmother.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother') OR rfather.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather')
```

Code working so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT  p.pk_PupilID, pn.Title, pn.Forename, pn.Surname, pn.PreferredForename, father.pk_PersonID, father.Title, father.Forename, father.Surname,  mother.pk_PersonID, mother.Title, mother.Forename, mother.Surname, pn.DoB, pn.Gender, h.House, p.Form, p.BoardingStatus, p.Tutor, h.Housemaster , f.Salutation
FROM Family AS f 
LEFT JOIN RELATION AS rpupil ON f.pk_FamilyID = rpupil.fk_FamilyID
LEFT JOIN PUPIL AS p ON rpupil.fk_PersonID = p.pk_PupilID 
LEFT JOIN PERSON AS pn ON p.pk_PupilID = pn.pk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN HOUSE AS h ON p.fk_DepartmentID = h.fk_DepartmentID 
LEFT JOIN RELATION AS rfather ON p.pk_PupilID = rfather.fk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN PERSON AS father ON rfather.fk_RelatedPersonID = father.pk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN RELATION AS rmother ON p.pk_PupilID = rmother.fk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN PERSON AS mother ON rmother.fk_RelatedPersonID = mother.pk_PersonID 
WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "')
```

Comment: You are killing the `LEFT JOIN` by your `WHERE` clause.  This is effectively transforming it into an `INNER JOIN`.  Any further filtering on the right-hand table of a `LEFT JOIN` (or to the left-hand table of a `RIGHT JOIN`) needs to be added to the `ON` clause conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatted comment here.

One thing to note about `OR`...

This:

```
WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') 
AND rmother.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother') 
OR rfather.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather')
```

Is processed like this:

```
WHERE (
     p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') 
AND  rmother.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother')
      )
OR   rfather.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather')
```

You need to use parenthesis `()` to define the part of your `WHERE` clause that you want the `OR` to apply to:

```
WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') 
AND (
     rmother.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother') 
OR   rfather.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather')
    )
```

This way both of your `OR` clause options will also have to fulfill `WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "')`

Anyway, I don't have enough information to know if this will actually solve your issue.  Some example data would help so we could know what is returning that shouldn't be, or what isn't that should.

Answer (score -1):

If you know for sure that one of the four "parent" values will be populated you could use this:

```
where(p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') AND rmother.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother')) or (p.pk_PupilID in('" & pks & "') AND rfather.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather'))
```